# discrepency in command line argument vs .sed file input

Tags: sed, command-line, command-prompt

So I have a project that uses sed and bash and I'm trying to understand why on a command line output it gives me one value whereas in actual project it gives me a different value.

In the command line I'm executing

```
sed 's/||/ || /g' filename
```

and in the sed file I'm inputting

```
s/||/ || /g
```

Now the first command in the command line gives me the proper output but I'm trying to understand why when I use the command in the sed file it's not giving me the same output.
In the bash file I have I'm calling the sed file as such

```
sed -rf sedFile $1
```

and then running the program as

```
./bashfile.bash fileName
```

Comment: Since the command has a space, have you tried placing the command in the file inside quotes?

Comment: yeah i tried that and it gives an error code :  unknown command ` " '

Comment: @AntonioCampos, if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60694422/5825294) is not what you expect, please include in your question that output that you expect as well as the output that you obtain.

Comment: Why are using the `-r` option? as @EnricoMariaDeAngelis has pointed out this effects of the regexp. BTW `-r` is equivalent to `-E`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/||/ || /g' filename
```

is totatlly different from

```
sed -rf sedFile filename
```

The latter is essentially

```
sed -r 's/||/ || /g' filename
```

and it will generate a totally different results because of `-r` will change the meaning of `|` from literal vertial bar to alternation. Thus, the `||` in the search pattern matches a zero length string, or a zero length string, or a zero length string, which means it will match any position (zero length) between the characters (including before the first character and after the last character).

```
echo ,,,, | sed -r 's/||/_||_/g' # underscores for visibility in the output
```

has the following output

```
_||_,_||_,_||_,_||_,_||_
```

By the way, `s/|/ || /g` would have the same effect, whereas `s// || /g` is invalid.

Comment: ahh ok i see why it wasnt doing what i wanted it to. But the output that i am looking for is basically to add a space before and after the || character and fix the spacing between it.

Comment: @AntonioCampos then what? Please, edit your question and show a sample input and a sample output! The answer slightly depends on wether in the input file `||` has no space around it, or only one (only left or only right, both both), or whatever.